# Issue with ActionListener

Tags: java, message

I run this script and when i click add it works and adds the 2 boxes but when i click any other button it doesnt open a box with the answer. I dont know why the message box doesnt open with the answer on any of them but the add could anyone explain and tell me a fix. The code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

    private JButton reg;
    private JButton reg2;
    private JButton reg3;
    private JButton reg4;
    private JTextField text;
    private JTextField text2;
    private JTextField text3;
    private JTextField text4;
    private JTextField text5;
    private JTextField text6;
    private JTextField text7;
    private JTextField text8;


    public Gui(){
        super("Buttons");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());



        text = new JTextField(20);
        text2 = new JTextField(20);
        text3 = new JTextField(20);
        text4 = new JTextField(20);
        text5 = new JTextField(20);
        text6 = new JTextField(20);
        text7 = new JTextField(20);
        text8 = new JTextField(20);
        reg = new JButton("Add");
        reg2 = new JButton("Divide");
        reg3 = new JButton("Multiply");
        reg4 = new JButton("Subtract");

        add(text);
        add(text2);
        add(reg);
        add(text3);
        add(text4);
        add(reg2);
        add(text5);
        add(text6);
        add(reg3);
        add(text7);
        add(text8);
        add(reg4);



        handlerClass handler = new handlerClass();
        reg.addActionListener(handler);
        reg2.addActionListener(handler);
        reg3.addActionListener(handler);
        reg4.addActionListener(handler);






    }

    public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String st = text.getText();
            String st2 = text.getText();
            String st3 = text.getText();
            String st4 = text.getText();
            String st5 = text.getText();
            String st6 = text.getText();
            String st7 = text.getText();
            String st8 = text.getText();

            int txt1 = Integer.parseInt(st);
            int txt2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int txt3 = Integer.parseInt(st3);
            int txt4 = Integer.parseInt(st4);
            int txt5 = Integer.parseInt(st5);
            int txt6 = Integer.parseInt(st6);
            int txt7 = Integer.parseInt(st7);
            int txt8 = Integer.parseInt(st8);


            if(event.getActionCommand()=="Add"){
                int add=txt1+txt2;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add));
            }

            if(event.getActionCommand()=="Divide"){
                if(txt4>0){
                    int add2=txt3/txt4;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add2));
                }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Cannot divide by zero"));
                }
            }

            if(event.getActionCommand()=="Multiply"){
                int add3=txt5*txt6;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add3));
            }

            if(event.getActionCommand()=="Subtract"){
                int add4=txt7-txt8;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont get an error they just dont open

Comment: If you're looking for help, you need to make a much simpler test-case.  See http://sscce.org.

Comment: Also consider using a debugger, log statements/dialogs, etc. to try to narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: Im relatively new to java i dont know what i could do to simplify the if statements

Comment: its like the 2nd week coding java O.0

Comment: How do you expect some one to help you with this Question Title

Comment: for some reason its working now but giving me the wrong answers for them

Comment: I realized that the code is wrong wrong wrong... wrong lol im just using the same text field for all of them O.0

Comment: Atleast microsoft would buy it. nice and buggy

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares equality of refrences.

`.equals()` compares String's value.

```
if("Multiply".equals(event.getActionCommand()))
{

}
```

Comment: I suggest you put the String literal first to avoid unwittingly throwing a NPE. i.e., `if ("Multiply".equals(event.getActionCommand())) {}`. 1+